# Pycharm importing shutil from *.pyi instead of *.py

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, shutil, pyenv

**Setup:**

OSX Sierra 10.12.6

Pycharm Community (2018.1.4)

pyenvs + pyenv-virtualenv:

```
2.7.15/envs/DAEnv (created from /Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15)
2.7.15/envs/python2 (created from /Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15)
3.7.0/envs/python3 (created from /Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0)
DAEnv (created from /Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15)
python2 (created from /Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15)
python3 (created from /Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/3.7.0)
```

Project interpreter is setup to use DAEnv

**Problem:**

importing private methods from shutil (example below) gives Cannot find reference.

```
from shutil import _basename
```

When I "click" on shutil, it redirects to **/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/helpers/typeshed/stdlib/2/shutil.pyi** instead of **/Users/milena/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/shutil.py**

**Solution?**

May it be connected with .bash_profile that is configured as part of 
[pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv) configuration? PyCharm is not inheriting bash profile?

How to tell PyCharm to use .py instead of .pyi?

How to tell Pycharm to use my .bash_profile?

I'm in the dark here.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm relies on [typeshed stubs](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/shutil.pyi) to retrieve a list of importable objects from `shutil`, unfortunately, it's lacking `_basename`. I created a corresponding ticket in PyCharms' bug tracker: [PY-30842](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30842).